# How to determine a Unicode word is wide or narrow (east asian width) in terminal?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, widechar

I have already checked this document:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/EastAsianWidth.txt

and this one:

https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c

(actually, `wcwitdh` is Unicode 5.0 version of east asian width).

But some words, such as `‧` (`"\u2027"` in C++), are *ambiguous* in east asian width.

In *Linux*, it is as narrow as plain alphabet (such as `a`).

However, in *Windows*, it is as wide as Chinese word (such as `我`).

Besides, for some words, such as `®` (`"\u00ae"` in C++), are also *ambiguous* in east asian width.

But `®` is as narrow as plain alphabet in both *Linux* and *Windows*.

How to correctly determine if a Unicode word is wide or narrow in different platforms? (for *ambiguous* words).

Comment: Windows does not deal in UTF-8 to begin with, APIs operate on strings encoded in either ANSI (using a local user-defined charset) or UTF-16.  Linux is primarily UTF-8 instead.  You need to pay attention to the charset encoding that you are working with.  ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-16, they all encode the same data in different ways. [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: What's the problem? If the width of a character is "ambiguous" in `EastAsianWidth.txt`, you need to look at the surrounding context to determine the width: http://unicode.org/reports/tr11/#Ambiguous

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, but the problem is not encoding. What I want to know is how many columns (the width after cout or printf in terminal) are occupied by a Unicode word. I am not talking about how to determine `bytes count` of a Unicode. But thank you for your replying.

Comment: @一二三 I will read the paragraph more carefully.